# SQL using two subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am learning about SQL subqueries. Here is the subquery I am using from the book:

```
SELECT account_id, product_cd, cust_id
FROM account
WHERE open_branch_id = (
    SELECT branch_id
    FROM branch
    WHERE name = 'Woburn Branch'
) AND open_emp_id IN (
    SELECT emp_id
    FROM employee
    WHERE title = 'Teller' OR title = 'Head Teller'
);
```

Result:

```
+------------+------------+---------+
| account_id | product_cd | cust_id |
+------------+------------+---------+
|          1 | CHK        |       1 |
|          2 | SAV        |       1 |
|          3 | CD         |       1 |
|          4 | CHK        |       2 |
|          5 | SAV        |       2 |
|         17 | CD         |       7 |
|         27 | BUS        |      11 |
+------------+------------+---------+
```

I have looked over this query trying to interpret it and understand it as well as the reasoning behind it's clauses but, I fail to understand the reason for the last `AND` clause `AND open_emp_id IN`...

I noticed that with just

```
SELECT account_id, product_cd, cust_id
FROM account
WHERE open_branch_id = (
    SELECT branch_id
    FROM branch
    WHERE name = 'Woburn Branch'
)
```

You get the same result as above. Can anyone explain to me the reasoning behind the last `AND open_emp_id IN` clause and how omitting it would affect the final result?

Tables used in subquery:

Account table

```
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| account_id | product_cd | cust_id | open_date  | close_date | last_activity_date | status | open_branch_id | open_emp_id | avail_balance | pending_balance |
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
|          1 | CHK        |       1 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2005-01-04         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       1057.75 |         1057.75 |
|          2 | SAV        |       1 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2004-12-19         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |        500.00 |          500.00 |
|          3 | CD         |       1 | 2004-06-30 | NULL       | 2004-06-30         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       3000.00 |         3000.00 |
|          4 | CHK        |       2 | 2001-03-12 | NULL       | 2004-12-27         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       2258.02 |         2258.02 |
|          5 | SAV        |       2 | 2001-03-12 | NULL       | 2004-12-11         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |        200.00 |          200.00 |
|          7 | CHK        |       3 | 2002-11-23 | NULL       | 2004-11-30         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |       1057.75 |         1057.75 |
|          8 | MM         |       3 | 2002-12-15 | NULL       | 2004-12-05         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |       2212.50 |         2212.50 |
|         10 | CHK        |       4 | 2003-09-12 | NULL       | 2005-01-03         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        534.12 |          534.12 |
|         11 | SAV        |       4 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2004-10-24         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        767.77 |          767.77 |
|         12 | MM         |       4 | 2004-09-30 | NULL       | 2004-11-11         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       5487.09 |         5487.09 |
|         13 | CHK        |       5 | 2004-01-27 | NULL       | 2005-01-05         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |       2237.97 |         2897.97 |
|         14 | CHK        |       6 | 2002-08-24 | NULL       | 2004-11-29         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        122.37 |          122.37 |
|         15 | CD         |       6 | 2004-12-28 | NULL       | 2004-12-28         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |      10000.00 |        10000.00 |
|         17 | CD         |       7 | 2004-01-12 | NULL       | 2004-01-12         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       5000.00 |         5000.00 |
|         18 | CHK        |       8 | 2001-05-23 | NULL       | 2005-01-03         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |       3487.19 |         3487.19 |
|         19 | SAV        |       8 | 2001-05-23 | NULL       | 2004-10-12         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |        387.99 |          387.99 |
|         21 | CHK        |       9 | 2003-07-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        125.67 |          125.67 |
|         22 | MM         |       9 | 2004-10-28 | NULL       | 2004-10-28         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       9345.55 |         9845.55 |
|         23 | CD         |       9 | 2004-06-30 | NULL       | 2004-06-30         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       1500.00 |         1500.00 |
|         24 | CHK        |      10 | 2002-09-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |      23575.12 |        23575.12 |
|         25 | BUS        |      10 | 2002-10-01 | NULL       | 2004-08-28         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |          0.00 |            0.00 |
|         27 | BUS        |      11 | 2004-03-22 | NULL       | 2004-11-14         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       9345.55 |         9345.55 |
|         28 | CHK        |      12 | 2003-07-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |      38552.05 |        38552.05 |
|         29 | SBL        |      13 | 2004-02-22 | NULL       | 2004-12-17         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |      50000.00 |        50000.00 |
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Branch table:

```
+-----------+---------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-------+
| branch_id | name          | address              | city    | state | zip   |
+-----------+---------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|         1 | Headquarters  | 3882 Main St.        | Waltham | MA    | 02451 |
|         2 | Woburn Branch | 422 Maple St.        | Woburn  | MA    | 01801 |
|         3 | Quincy Branch | 125 Presidential Way | Quincy  | MA    | 02169 |
|         4 | So. NH Branch | 378 Maynard Ln.      | Salem   | NH    | 03079 |
+-----------+---------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Employee table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| emp_id | fname    | lname     | start_date | end_date | superior_emp_id | dept_id | title              | assigned_branch_id |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      1 | Michael  | Smith     | 2005-06-22 | NULL     |            NULL |       3 | President          |                  1 |
|      2 | Susan    | Barker    | 2006-09-12 | NULL     |               1 |       3 | Vice President     |                  1 |
|      3 | Robert   | Tyler     | 2005-02-09 | NULL     |               1 |       3 | Treasurer          |                  1 |
|      4 | Susan    | Hawthorne | 2006-04-24 | NULL     |               3 |       1 | Operations Manager |                  1 |
|      5 | John     | Gooding   | 2007-11-14 | NULL     |               4 |       2 | Loan Manager       |                  1 |
|      6 | Helen    | Fleming   | 2008-03-17 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  1 |
|      7 | Chris    | Tucker    | 2008-09-15 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|      8 | Sarah    | Parker    | 2006-12-02 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|      9 | Jane     | Grossman  | 2006-05-03 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|     10 | Paula    | Roberts   | 2006-07-27 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  2 |
|     11 | Thomas   | Ziegler   | 2004-10-23 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
|     12 | Samantha | Jameson   | 2007-01-08 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
|     13 | John     | Blake     | 2004-05-11 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  3 |
|     14 | Cindy    | Mason     | 2006-08-09 | NULL     |              13 |       1 | Teller             |                  3 |
|     15 | Frank    | Portman   | 2007-04-01 | NULL     |              13 |       1 | Teller             |                  3 |
|     16 | Theresa  | Markham   | 2005-03-15 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  4 |
|     17 | Beth     | Fowler    | 2006-06-29 | NULL     |              16 |       1 | Teller             |                  4 |
|     18 | Rick     | Tulman    | 2006-12-12 | NULL     |              16 |       1 | Teller             |                  4 |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AND open_emp_id IN clause is selecting only the employee ids whose title is 'Teller' or 'Head Teller'. In your case the result is not different because you are looking for branch with the name 'Woburn Branch', and it is just a coincidence that all the employees there are of title 'Teller' or 'Head Teller' only.

```
|     10 | Paula    | Roberts   | 2006-07-27 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  2 |

|     11 | Thomas   | Ziegler   | 2004-10-23 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |

|     12 | Samantha | Jameson   | 2007-01-08 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
```

Change the branch name to 'Headquarters' in the first query, and you will see the difference that the subquery makes. Any employees at the 'Headquarters' who do not have title 'Teller' or 'Head Teller' will get excluded.

Answer (score 1):

The last AND narrows the selection criteria to include only accounts that were open by a Teller or Head Teller. If the Loan Manager or Operations Manager had opened the account it would be excluded.